# Testing VMware replication on the same storage

Tags: vmware-esxi, replication

We have two sites setup with VMware Site Recovery Manager (SRM) using VMware Replication to synchronize VMs. I need to validate the procedure for the site switch-over but I can use only one site.

My idea is to simulate the remote site by utilizing extra hardware. I have spare physical ESXi host to use. Network would be separated by the use of VLANs and it seems to me everything should work this way.

One thing that I am worried about is storage. Currently 'spare' ESXi host is configured to use the same storage (HP P2000 SAN) as the main host. I am not sure will this create conflict during the Replication - e.g. will the VMware replication be confused if it is using same path for storing the VMs?

Comment: `I need to validate the procedure for the site switch-over but I can use only one site` - That's really not a validation is it? What happens if your limited test works but a site switch-over fails in a real scenario?

Comment: There will be other tests as well, including tests on the production system. My task at this point is to check if the switchover works in the setup as I described.